# Yii prevent re-inserting data to database from uploaded file on refresh

Tags: php, yii

I have an upload form, where I upload csv files and then insert all rows to the database. If I hit refresh, all content is inserted again and again into the database. What is the best prectice to prevent this?

Thanks a lot!
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to prevent this behavior is to use a redirect to show the landing page. When a redirect is made the browser history records another url after the post action. in Yii you can achieve this by doing the following from the controller.

```
 $this->redirect("../path/to/action");
```

Comment: thank you very much, I like this solution. simple and Yii-like.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden input element to the form which holds a unique ID:

```
<input type="hidden" name="random" value="4b3403665fea6">
```

If you store this value in the database you can make sure that no CSV file will be uploaded with the same unique ID (after refresh).

A unique ID can be generated with a built-in PHP function [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)